# white-space: pre-line Not Honored in Element with contentediatble="true"

Tags: css, html, contenteditable

I'm using contenteditable="true" to edit a div with white-space: pre-line and found that the formatting is not being honored. It simply collapse all white spaces. Is there a way to make this happen?

```
Line 1

Line 2
```

Becomes

```
Line1 Line2
```

Which is not good since user is not able to see what they are editing. I understand there is an issue with extra  being introduce for every enter key, but that one is easier to handle once it's displayed correctly.

Comment: Did you test it in all browsers? Which browser are you using when you see this?

Comment: I have tested with latest version of Chrome so far.

Comment: It seems that the only way is to use <pre> tag.

Comment: are you using any style sheets that may be overriding? Are you writing the app from scratch or are you modifying an existing app?

Comment: I tried it just now and it seems to be okay. I think the issue was to do with CKEditor introducing tags in the content. Now that I have introduced code to clean them out, it seems to be okay. I essentially switch to use <br> tag instead of <p> or <div> and replace them with new line character between saving the data.